# Como contornar uma situação sql onde eu não tenha todas as informações

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou utilizando a linguagem de programação php onde:

Tenho o seguinte metódo de uma classe:

```
public function executaquery($s, $con) {
    $query = '';
    $total = 0;
    $s = str_replace(".", ";", $s);
    $s = str_replace(",", ";", $s);
    $s = str_replace(" ", ";", $s);

    $resultados = (explode(";",$s));

    $total = count($resultados);

    if ($total >= 1) {
        foreach ($resultados as $resultado) {
            if ($query == '') {
                $query = "SELECT resposta FROM suporte where pergunta like '%".$resultado."%'";
            }
            else {
               $query = "{$query} and  pergunta like '%".$resultado."%'";
            }
        }
    }               

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die();

    return $result;
}
```

Quando eu digito por exemplo a seguinte frase: **instalação do windows**.

Meu método me retorna 1 registro na minha consulta;

Porem se eu coloco **instalação configuração windows**, como eu tenho duas perguntas no meu banco ou contendo instalação ou contendo configuração meu programa não traz nenhum pois como estou usando o operador AND na minha consulta o programa não consegue localizar os três termos acima no caso eu conseguiria trazer as informações se eu conseguisse trocando o operador para OR na minha consulta.

Alguem conhece algum mecanismo para contornar uma situação assim? será que vou ter que colocar uma consulta e verificar o retorno senão retornar nada a mesma consulta mudando o operador?

Comment: Você precisa definir o que deseja como retorno. Se quiser que as respostas contenham TODOS os termos então utilize AND, se quiser que a resposta contenha PELO MENOS UM dos termos então utilize OR. A especificação de sua aplicação é que irá determinar como você deve implementar o SELECT. Se for alguma outra alternativa a estas duas então terá que estudar como implementar. Dê uma avaliada se as funções de Full-Text Search não podem ajuda-lo com a solução [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html].

Answer (score 0):

SELECTs com LIKE são pouco performáticos.
Minha sugestão para essa situação seria você separar o conteúdo da sua coluna "resposta" em "palavras" no momento que está cadastrando. Posteriormente você associa cada palavra a esse registro de suporte.

Quando for realizar o SELECT, você busca pelas palavras e identifica os registros de suporte associados. Dessa maneira você consegue até ordenar por registros mais relevantes.